# Пунктуация, в частности присоединительный оборот с "особенно", запятая перед "в первую очередь"

Tags: пунктуация

> Закладываемыми в Национальную программу общими ожидаемыми результатами являются:
>   <...>
>
> • увеличение ожидаемой продолжительности жизни населения за счет сохранения и улучшения здоровья и качества жизни населения, снижение преждевременной, особенно - предотвратимой смертности, в первую очередь - в младенческих возрастах, среди подростков и лиц трудоспособного возраста; 
>   <...>

(это один пункт из перечня)

Интересует присоединительный оборот с "особенно", если это он; тире (оба знака); запятая перед "в первую очередь". Верно ли расставлены?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. У меня вызывает сомнение оборот "за счет" в данном контексте. Мы говорим "за счет"

   - когда одно улучшается, а другое ухудшается (оно за счет другого);
   - когда кто-то платит (за счет налогоплательщиков);
   - когда имеется в виду вклад части в целое (объём активов возрос почти в два раза, в основном за счёт роста резервных активов).

А в приведенном тексте я бы написал "путем".

2. Вам следует проверить, что имел в виду автор. Либо общими ожидаемыми результатами являются увеличение ожидаемой продолжительности жизни и  снижение смертности. (Так в тексте, но это нелогично). Либо увеличение ожидаемой продолжительности жизни путем снижения смертности. (Так у Ксении, и это логично).
3. Качество повышают, не улучшают.
4. Младенческий возраст — известный термин, откуда у автора мн. ч.?
5. Неясно, куда относится "в первую очередь", только к младенцам или ко всем перечисленным категориям. Полагаю, что ко всем. Тогда так: "в первую очередь  среди младенцев, подростков и лиц трудоспособного возраста".
6. Предложенные тире — интонационные, а это, на мой взглад, значит, что ставить их в официальном тексте не следует. Но если это газетная статья, то почему бы и не поставить?

Answer (score 1):

• увеличение ожидаемой продолжительности **жизни населения** за счет сохранения и улучшения здоровья и качества **жизни населения**, снижение преждевременной, особенно — предотвратимой смертности, в первую очередь — в младенческих **возрастах**, среди подростков и лиц трудоспособного **возраста**;

Пояснение

1) Преждевременной, особенно — предотвратимой смертности.

Второе определение уточняющее, но оно оформлено как однородное из-за большого количества знаков в тексте. Тире интонационное, для правильного понимания значения наречия при его интонационном выделении.

2) И в первую очередь — в младенческой группе.

Тире также интонационное, чтобы показать, что наречие относится ко всему ряду.

Comment: Вы изменили смысл, возможно это логично, но нужно спросить у автора. У автора ожидаемыми результатами являются: (1) увеличение ожидаемой продолжительности жизни (2) снижение смертности. У Вас: увеличение ожидаемой продолжительности жизни за счет снижения смертности.

Comment: Возвращаемся к предложенному варианту. Лучше ничего не изменять:  стилистику исправить сложно, а вопрос был по пунктуации.